# Best method to check for new woocommerce orders?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

A developer was hired to make me a plugin that checks continuously for new orders being placed on my woocommerce site. When a new order is detected, it will sound aaudible alarm.

He hooked into admin-ajax, which checks every 10 seconds. Works relatively well, but everyone admin-ajax is called, cpu utilisation hits 100% for a few seconds.

Just wondering if there are any alternative methods that isn’t so resource heavy.

Thanks

Comment: alternative to... what existing method?

Comment: Using admin-ajax.php (the heartbeat api I believe)

Comment: Use the emails that WooCommerce generates.  You can use IFTTT to generate notifcations https://ifttt.com/applets/ZqxgtfTM-get-a-notification-when-you-get-an-email-from-a-specific-person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using a [WooCommerce webhook](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/webhooks/). A WooCommerce webhook can send a notification to a URL that you specify when an order is created. This is done as part of the request to create the order so very little additional overhead is incurred. Polling is very inefficient as it periodically creates a new request and in many cases the request doesn't yield a useful result. Webhooks are intended to solve this problem.

To create the webhook using the dashboard go to WooCommerce -> API -> Webhooks -> Add webhook. Of course you will need write the handler for this HTTP request.

Comment: Currently a user will need to log into the WP-Admin dashboard and navigate to the woocommerce > orders page in order for my current plugin to start polling and setting the audible alarm off.

If we are to use webhooks, how do we make the woocommerce > orders page to "listen" for the webhook? Will this be javascript?